# Adding two vectors by names

Tags: r, vector, aggregate, addition, names

I have two named vectors

```
v1 <- 1:4
v2 <- 3:5
names(v1) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
names(v2) <- c("c", "e", "d")
```

I want to add them up by the names, i.e. the expected result is

```
> v3  
a b c d e   
1 2 6 9 4
```

Is there a way to programmatically do this in R? Note the names may not necessarily be in a sorted order, like in `v2` above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just combine the vectors (using `c`, for example) and use `tapply`:

```
v3 <- c(v1, v2)
tapply(v3, names(v3), sum)
# a b c d e 
# 1 2 6 9 4
```

Or, for fun (since you're just doing `sum`), continuing with "v3":

```
xtabs(v3 ~ names(v3))
# names(v3)
# a b c d e 
# 1 2 6 9 4
```

---

I suppose with "data.table" you could also do something like:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(Reduce(c, mget(ls(pattern = "v\\d"))), 
              keep.rownames = TRUE)[, list(V2 = sum(V2)), by = V1]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  a  1
# 2:  b  2
# 3:  c  6
# 4:  d  9
# 5:  e  4
```

(I shared the latter not so much for "data.table" but to show an automated way of capturing the vectors of interest.)

Comment: I always find that people who understands R writes code in a totally different way... sometimes even feel like you are writing in a different language :) (absolutely compliment!)

Comment: @RichardScriven, for the most part, `tapply` is the workhorse for `aggregate` (and `by`) so from the point where the vectors have been combined, there are several alternatives.

Comment: This might be a late compliment, but this is really beautiful @AHandcartAndMohair! The `xtabs` and `tapply` come in really handy when trying to combine frequency tables, and they are pretty under-used imo.